# Why I can't escape the question mark (C#)?

Tags: c#

I need to count how many times each words occurs in a text read from file . The problem is that I must escape some of the common symbols and I'm doing it. All of them are removing successfully except the question mark "?" and I still can't realize why is that happening. I'm referring the code. Thanks again.

```
namespace DictionariesHashTablesAndSets
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class WordsOccurencesInText
{
    static void Main()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("../../text.txt");
        string textFromFile = reader.ReadToEnd();

        string[] words = SplitWords(textFromFile);

        for (int index = 0; index <= words.Length - 1; index++)
        {
            words[index] = words[index].ToLower();
        }

        IDictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            int count = 1;
            if (dict.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                count = dict[word] + 1;
            }

            dict[word] = count;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(textFromFile);

        foreach (var word in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1} times", word.Key, word.Value);
        }

    }

    private static string[] SplitWords(string textFromFile)
    {
        char[] separators = new char[] { '.', ',', ' ', '?', '!', ';', '-' };
        string[] words = textFromFile.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return words;
    }
}
}
```

And the output:

```
just -> 1 times
some -> 1 times
random -> 3 times
text -> 11 times
over -> 1 times
here -> 1 times
and -> 1 times
more -> 1 times
this -> 3 times
is -> 2 times
the -> 2 times
? -> 1 times
```

Sample of the text file:

> just Some random text over Here, TEXT, text, and more random - random text Text? This is the TEXT. Text, text, text  THIS TEXT! Is this the text?

Comment: Does the input file contain a double questionmark `??`  ?

Comment: Not that it should matter if it did.

Comment: Is the input file in the right encoding?

Comment: ANSI - the default one.

Comment: You should include the input `textFromFile` string so your problem can be reproduced without guesswork.

Comment: can you post the text file please

Comment: Show us a sample of text

Comment: You need to include the actual *string*, not a random file

Comment: Okey, I refer the file, you can check the topic again @DeeMac

Comment: Is the `?` actually in the collection or is it just an output on the console? Keep in mind that console fonts and code page might not be able to display the actual character. Also `String.ToLower` depends on the current culture.

Comment: One thing's for sure, it has definitely recognised your question mark as a delimiter, as it's counted 11 occurences of `text`. I suspect this is a curve ball.

Comment: I have `text` in the output - it occurs 11 times, and have a look that I'm using on each `word.ToLower()` (case insensitive) @DeeMac

Comment: The way to solve this is to evaluate `words` using a breakpoint right before it's returned, your answer will be in there. I don't think you'll find a question mark in there.

Comment: And something interesting - have a look that once the question mark is escaped, once is not, because I have 2 times this separated with ? @DeeMac

Comment: I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: @StanimirYakimov - my point is that it IS 'escaped' both times. That method isn't your problem, the problem is elsewhere. I suspect with how the console is choosing the output a different character.

Comment: i copied your code and its working perfectly .

Comment: @KugBuBu solved the problem. Once again, thank you so much guys. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console wrote `?` because it's a character it can't display. That character is found at your file between those parts:

```
just Some random text over Here, TEXT, text, and more random - random text Text? This is the TEXT. Text, text, text
```

.

```
 THIS TEXT! Is this the text?
```

You see the space in the start? It isn't ordinary space and not a space from the first part. However it's ASCII value is 150. (The ordinary space's ASCII value is 32)
If you delete this extraordinary space that `?` will disappear.

If you want to check take this test:

```
just Some random text over Here, TEXT, text, and more random - random text Text? This is the TEXT. Text, text, text THIS TEXT! Is this the text?
```

Comment: I have just start wondering why when I delete the `?` from file, I'm still receiving that in the output. :D

Comment: @StanimirYakimov I started to wonder because it show ? in the wrong place. You were close :D.